# Representation of a training and validation metric in a pipeline

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn, pipeline

I have a problem. I want to plot my RMSE value. However, I now use a pipeline because I use cross-validation and also use other steps like feature selection.

My question is, is there a way to get this plot through the pipeline (without training the model a second time)? So how can I display the training and validation RMSE value nicely in a diagram in the pipeline?

Pipeline

```py
dfListingsFeature_regression = pd.read_csv(r"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Coderanker3/dataset4/main/listings_cleaned.csv")
d = {True: 1, False: 0, np.nan : np.nan} 
dfListingsFeature_regression['host_is_superhost'] = dfListingsFeature_regression[
                                                             'host_is_superhost'].map(d).astype('int')

X = dfListingsFeature_regression.drop(columns=['host_id', 'id', 'price']) # Features
y = dfListingsFeature_regression['price'] # Target variable
print(dfListingsFeature_nor.shape)

steps = [('feature_selection', SelectFromModel(estimator=LogisticRegression(max_iter=10000))),
         ('lasso', Lasso(alpha=0.4))]

pipeline = Pipeline(steps) 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=30)


parameteres = { }

grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=parameteres, cv=5)                
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
                    
print("score = %3.2f" %(grid.score(X_test,y_test)))
print('Training set score: ' + str(grid.score(X_train,y_train)))
print('Test set score: ' + str(grid.score(X_test,y_test)))


y_pred = grid.predict(X_test)

print("RMSE Val:", metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred, squared=False))

y_train_predict = grid.predict(X_train)
print("Train:" , metrics.mean_squared_error(y_train, y_train_predict , squared=False))

r2 = metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
print(r2)
```

Plot

```py
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def plot_learning_curves(model, X, y):
    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=10)
    train_errors, val_errors = [], []
    for m in range(1, 500 + 1):
        model.fit(X_train[:m], y_train[:m])
        y_train_predict = model.predict(X_train[:m])
        y_val_predict = model.predict(X_val)
        train_errors.append(mean_squared_error(y_train[:m], y_train_predict))
        val_errors.append(mean_squared_error(y_val, y_val_predict))

    plt.figure( figsize=(10,10))
    plt.plot(np.sqrt(train_errors), "r-+", linewidth=2, label="train")
    plt.plot(np.sqrt(val_errors), "b-", linewidth=3, label="val")
    plt.legend(loc="upper right", fontsize=14)   
    plt.xlabel("Training set size", fontsize=14) 
    plt.ylabel("RMSE", fontsize=14)              


%%time
lin_reg = Lasso(alpha=0.1)
plot_learning_curves(lin_reg, X, y)
#plt.axis([0, 80, 0, 3])                       
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to `fit()` your model again in `plot_learning_curves`. You can simply use your fitted pipeline to predict value for both train and validation  set and then plot your learning curve.

You function should look as follow without the `model.fit()`:

```
def plot_learning_curves(model, X, y):
    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=10)
    train_errors, val_errors = [], []
    for m in range(1, 500 + 1):
        y_train_predict = model.predict(X_train[:m])
        y_val_predict = model.predict(X_val)
        train_errors.append(mean_squared_error(y_train[:m], y_train_predict))
        val_errors.append(mean_squared_error(y_val, y_val_predict))

    plt.figure( figsize=(10,10))
    plt.plot(np.sqrt(train_errors), "r-+", linewidth=2, label="train")
    plt.plot(np.sqrt(val_errors), "b-", linewidth=3, label="val")
    plt.legend(loc="upper right", fontsize=14)   
    plt.xlabel("Training set size", fontsize=14) 
    plt.ylabel("RMSE", fontsize=14)
```

Then you should call this function using your fitted model as parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And how could I do this ?

Comment: I added the corrected version of your function without the `model.fit()`.